# Uncaught Error: Class 'BreweryDBSDK\BreweryDBSDK' not found

Tags: php

I've created an SDK for BreweryDB.com but when I use it in index.php I get an error

> Uncaught Error: Class 'BreweryDBSDK\BreweryDBSDK' not found

BreweryDBSDK.php

```
<?php

namespace BreweryDBSDK;

use BreweryDBSDK\API\Beer as BeerAPI;
use BreweryDBSDK\HttpClient\HttpClientInterface;
use BreweryDBSDK\HttpClient\HttpClient;

class BreweryDBSDK
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $apiKey;

    /**
     * @var HttpClientInterface
     */
    private $httpClient;

    public function __construct($apiKey)
    {
        $this->apiKey = $apiKey;
        $this->httpClient = new HttpClient($this->apiKey);
    }

    public function beer()
    {
        return new BeerAPI($this);
    }
}
```

index.php

```
<?php

use BreweryDBSDK\BreweryDBSDK;

$breweryDBSDK = new BreweryDBSDK('ca162a740060a64de5658a4627ddb091');
?>

<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
Hello
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should include `BreweryDBSDK.php` in `index.php`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include `BreweryDBSDK.php` into your `index.php`

If you ave seperated your class logic correctly,

```
require_once __DIR__ . "/path/to/BreweryDBSDK/BreweryDBSDK.php";
```

should be used. Also don't forget to include all other files:

```
require_once __DIR__ . "/path/to/BreweryDBSDK/API/Beer.php";
require_once __DIR__ . "/path/to/BreweryDBSDK/HttpClient/HttpClientInterface.php";
require_once __DIR__ . "/path/to/BreweryDBSDK/HttpClient/HttpClient.php";
```

Another option would be setting up an autloader class and register the autloader with [spl_autoload_register](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php). When you set up a composer project, you can get the autloader feature for free ;)

**EDIT:**

For the composer solution, you have to add something like this to your composer.json

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": { "BreweryDBSDK\\": "path/to/classes/root/"}
}
```

then you have to make a composer install (or update) and then don't forget to include the autloadfile via:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
```

This has to be included into the `index.php` and all files, you were requesting directly. No need to include it in all classes, because they should all be loaded by other classes, which in return are first loaded by the `index.php`

Comment: I have composer set up, how do I do it with that?